# How do I choose backcolors of forms from code?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

So I was trying to change the backcolor of my form from code using the command "color" from system.drawing.color, but the options that it has (White, Gray, Silver, etc) are not the same as the ones that the designer offers (ButtonFace, ButtonHighlight, Control), so my question is if there is any type of way to set the exact same colors of the designer from the code.

Thank you so much for your time, hope you have a great day :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SystemColors` in `System.Drawing` instead of `Color`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemcolors